# how to get all directories under a file system

Tags: linux, mount

i have a file system with usaged 100%, 
[image]

so i want to see what kind of big files for that file system(/dev/vda4), 
and i used df -h --max-depth=1 /
[image]

but i can not find 47G used for /, is it possible that there are other directories for /dev/vda4 except for / ? 
if so, how to find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command to find big files (more than 100MB):

```
find / -xdev -size +100M
```

-xdev means exclude other mounted file systems.

To get all the mount points on one file system, you can do

```
df -a | grep vda5
```

Comment: thanks, my concern is: i suspect there is other directory except for /, how to find ?

Comment: The command I suggested is to find `other directories` under `/` which contain big files.